# run function at ready and keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there another in jquery to run a function at page load and at a keyup event instead of the way I'm doing it?

```
$(function() { 
  totalQty(); 
  $("#main input").keyup(function() { 
    totalQty(); 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: since jQuery 1.4 $() is no longer a shortcut to $(document); you should use $(document).ready( ... ) to execute something at page load.

Comment: +1 to David V. oh wow, i completely missed that...

Answer (score 4):

Disregarding `live` or `delegate` optimizations, you can trigger an event like this:

```
$(function() { 
   $("#main input").keyup(function() { 
     totalQty();
   }).filter(":first").keyup(); //Run it once
});
```

No need for the filter if it's not on multiple elements, just leave it out in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $(document).ready event to run functions on load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    /* your code here */ 
});
```

Comment: those are the same thing, I think he was referring to a better way to factor his code instead of different wording.

Comment: oops, i missed that in 1.4 $() is no longer the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You could use $.live(), which does event delegation, which is MUCH more efficient than created an event listener for every single input tag...and then missing any dynamically created ones. Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 totalQty();
 $('#main input').live('keyup', function() {
  totalQty();
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do (jQuery 1.4+ )

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  totalQty(); 
  $("#main").delegate("input","keyup",function() { 
    totalQty(); 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: why delegate instead of live? I thought live did event delegation?